# PHP: Resultado de If com Function

Tags: php, if

Estou a ter um pequeno problema ao usar If com uma function para mostrar um resultado.

```
function estaParaExpirar($data, $dias){
return(strtotime($data) < strtotime("+".$dias. "days") );
}


  if (estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10") ||
  estaParaExpirar($row[12], "10") ||  estaParaExpirar($row[13], "10") ||
  estaParaExpirar($row[14], "10") ||
  estaParaExpirar($row[15], "10") ||
  estaParaExpirar($row[16], "10") ||
  estaParaExpirar($row[17], "10")) {  
   $Nome1 = '<p>Nome: '.$row[10].'</p>' ;}
```

Fiz um pequeno teste com o código que o @jader deu.

```
$row[11] = '0000-00-00';
$row[12] = '2014-08-15';
$row[13] = '2014-08-15';
$row[14] = '2014-08-15';
$row[15] = '2014-08-15';
$row[16] = '2014-08-15';
$row[17] = '2014-08-15';

if (($row[11] != '0000-00-00' and $row[12] != '0000-00-00' and $row[13] 
!= '0000-00-   00'      and $row[14] != '0000-00-00' and $row[15] != '0000-00-00'
and $row[16] != '0000-00-00' and $row[17] != '0000-00-00')
and ((estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10")) and (estaParaExpirar($row[12], "10")) and 
(estaParaExpirar($row[13], "10")) and
(estaParaExpirar($row[14], "10")) and   
(estaParaExpirar($row[15], "10")) and 
(estaParaExpirar($row[16], "10")) and
(estaParaExpirar($row[17], "10")))) {
```

Resultado;

echo 'faltam mais de 10 dias'; 
Está errado

PS:
Alterei o código para mas estou com o problema ao mostrar o resultado. Se o resultado for 10 acima da data atual não mostra resultado nenhum

```
     if (($row[11] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10")) 
    || ($row[12] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[12], "10"))
    || ($row[13] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[13], "10")) 
    || ($row[14] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[14], "10")) 
    || ($row[15] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[15], "10")) 
    || ($row[16] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[16], "10")) 
    || ($row[17] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[17], "10"))) {     
    $Nome1 = '<p>Nome: '.$row[10].'</p>' ;}
```

Comment: Falta um espaço antes de "days". Se não for isso, talvez o formato de data que vem do seu banco não seja interpretável pelo `strtotime`.

Comment: Bom dia, qual é o problema? favor trocar $row[xx] por datas reais pois o problema pode ser o formatado da data.

Comment: Que formato de data você esta recebendo em $row[11...] ?

Comment: As datas vem no formato: Ano-Mes-Dia (0000-00-00 )

Comment: Mesmo com o espaço teima em não funcionar

Comment: Pode fazer `var_dump($row);` e colocar na pergunta para ficar mais claro o seu código e podermos ajudar?

Comment: 1- Coloque a condição de validação (verificação de datas vazias) dentro da sua função `estaParaExpirar`. 2- Por que raios você precisa comparar 7 datas de uma linha do banco de dados? Provavelmente seu design de tabelas está muito errado.

Comment: se alguma das 7 datas estiver a falta menos de 10 dias envia uma mensagem. Será o conteúdo de email.

Comment: Por que você está usando `and` e `&&` em vez de `||` (or) na funcão? Nesse caso seu `if` exige que todas as condições sejam satisfeitas.

Comment: Estou a tentar que o Row[??] seja diferente de 0000-00-00 e faltem 10 dias para terminar a condição. E isso para as outras todas

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que eu tenha entendido seu problema, tenho uma solução alternativa com base na classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime)

Seu problema parece girar em torno de uma comparação entre a data atual e uma data futura, ou seja, uma diferença de intervalos que, com a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) se resolve através de [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$currentDate = new DateTime;

$diff = $currentDate -> diff( new DateTime( $futureDate ) );
```

Simples assim! Para uma data 10 dias no futuro teremos em **$diff**:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 9
    [h] => 7
    [i] => 14
    [s] => 29
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 11
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

> A saída acima foi gerada com base num strtotime('+10 days') simples e, por isso, a entrada *d* parece errada ao mostrar 9, mas isso porque não foram informadas as horas, minutos e segundos.

Seu maior problema, no entanto, parece ser quanto a exibição. E, infelizmente, a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) dificulta um pouco as coisas pois pra ela não existem números negativos. Ao invés disso, quando a diferença computada for anterior à data-base (atual) a entrada **invert** é alterada de zero para um.

E é com isso que você trabalharia seus condicionais:

```
if( $diff -> invert == 0 ) {

    if( $diff -> d > 10 ) {

        return sprintf( '%d days remaining', $diff -> d );

    } else {

        return sprintf( 'Will expire in %d days', $diff -> d );
    }

} else {

    return sprintf( 'Expired %d days ago', $diff -> d );
}
```

Se a *flag* **invert** for zero, significa que a diferença é positiva, ou seja, a data futura é realmente futura. Daí é uma comparação simples: Se o número de dias for maior que os 10 que você definiu, mostramos que *ainda faltam X dias*. caso contrário mostramos que o prazo *expira em X dias*.

Caso a *flag* **invert** seja 1, temos que a data futura já passou, então apenas mostramos que *expirou há X dias*.

Como não sei onde isso vai ser usado, dependendo do caso você não vai mostrar que já se esgotou o prazo, ficando esse **else** facultativo ou para uso de outra forma que não a apresentada.

O código completo:

```
function showExpirationDate( $futureDate, $limit = 10 ) {

    $currentDate = new DateTime;

    $diff = $currentDate -> diff( new DateTime( $futureDate ) );

    if( $diff -> invert == 0 ) {

        if( $diff -> d > $limit ) {

            return sprintf( '%d days remaining', $diff -> d );

        } else {

            return sprintf( 'Will expire in %d days', $diff -> d );
        }

    } else {

        return sprintf( 'Expired %d days ago', $diff -> d );
    }
}
```

E a demonstração:

```
echo showExpirationDate( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '+10 days' ) ) ); // Will expire in 9 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua função não esta validando a data de entrada, adicionei a verificação para retornar false caso a data esteja invalida ou null e adicionei o valor padrão de dias:

```
function estaParaExpirar($data, $dias=10) {
    if (!strtotime($data) || empty($data)) return false;
    return(strtotime($data) < strtotime("+".$dias. "days") );
}

// Hoje é 12/08/2014

$row[11] = '0000-00-00';

if (estaParaExpirar($row[11])) {
    echo 'esta para expirar em menos de 10 dias';
} else {
    echo 'faltam mais de 10 dias';
}

//retorno
// faltam mais de 10 dias

$row[11] = '2014-08-20';

if (estaParaExpirar($row[11])) {
    echo 'esta para expirar em menos de 10 dias';
} else {
    echo 'faltam mais de 10 dias';
}

//retorno
// esta para expirar em menos de 10 dias
```

---

Bônus uma função que retorna os dias para expirar:

```
function diasParaExpirar($data) {
    if (!strtotime($data) || empty($data)) return false;
    return floor( ( strtotime($data) - strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) ) / 60 / 60 / 24 );
}

// Hoje é 12/08/2014

$row[11] = '2014-08-20';

echo 'faltam: '.diasParaExpirar($row[11]).' dias para expirar.';

//retorno
// faltam: 8 dias para expirar.
```

Comment: Acho que sei o que pode estar a originar este erro, São as datas que não tem resultado nenhum ou que tem a data com o valor de 0000-00-00

Comment: Na condição tenho de colocar algo "if ($row[11] != '0000-00-00' and (estaParaExpirar($row[11],"10")) || ($row[12] != '0000-00-00' and (estaParaExpirar($row[12],"10")) || " Correcto?

Comment: Corrija a função para retornar false caso seja zero ou null

Comment: Com null Funciona . O problema está a ser com datas com 0000-00-00

Comment: editei a resposta, veja como ficou a função.